# CSS or JS for list item with no children from sibling list item with children

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

I am creating a dropdown menu and want to add rounded borders on all four corners on hover if the main list item has no submenu, but I want only the top corners to be rounded on hover if the menu list item has a submenu. The submenu itself would not have any rounded borders and would blend into the tab of the parent. The HTML that creates the menu is derived from a WordPress function (wp_page_menu) which does not create different CSS classes for li tag without children versus li tag with children.

This CSS creates a dark gray rounded rectangle around the menu list item when a list item is moused-over. But I only want this effect if the menu list item is childless.

```
.menu ul li:hover a { 
    background:#111;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

---

Okay, so now the main menu list items that don't have children have 4 rounded borders, and the main menu list items that do have children have just the top rounded borders. So that is good. But .... now the children list items are also tabbed (i.e., the submenu is inheriting the style from the tabbed parent). I have fussed with the style sheet for hours and can't get what I want. The children list items should not have any rounded borders. Using the jQuery and/or CSS, how can I prevent the submenu from inheriting?

Comment: Okay, never mind my last comment. I got that working now too. Now I just have to figure out how to make the submenu be at least as long as the parent when the submenu links are all very short.

Comment: Last comment - I hope! Well the jQuery method does not work in IE9 (works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari). Does anyone know of a workaround for IE?

Comment: A keen and helpful user spotted an error in my CSS that IE didn't like. Fixed that and the jQuery works fine in IE9 now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have jQuery on that site then you can put something like this

```
$(function(){
  $('.menu li').has('ul').addClass('has-subitems');
});
```

this will add `has-subitems` class to all menu items that have sub menus. After that you can style them appropriately in CSS:

```
.menu li.has-subitems {  ... }
.menu li:not(.has-subitems) {  ... }
```

Comment: Okay, so now the main menu list items that don't have children have 4 rounded borders, and the main menu list items that do have children have just the top rounded borders. So that is good. But .... now the children list items are also tabbed (i.e., the submenu is inheriting the style from the tabbed parent). I have fussed with the style sheet for hours and can't get what I want. The children list items should not have any rounded borders. Using the jQuery and/or CSS, how can I prevent the submenu from inheriting the parent style?

Comment: As far as I understand you need something like:
`$('.menu li').has('>ul')` that will find all `li`'s that has `ul` as immediate child. No such thing in jQuery AFIAK. 
But to write such `hasChild(selector)` extension is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want certain corners to be rounded, you can use `border-top-left-radius` like this:

```
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
```

If you are trying to add this CSS to only `<li>` elements without children, you will have to use javascript/jQuery because it is not possible in CSS (yet). You can use the [solution that @c-smile posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543447/css-or-js-for-list-item-with-no-children-from-sibling-list-item-with-children/7543477#7543477) for that.

Comment: Thank you for responding rfausak. I did have the individual border CSS, I needed the JS/JQuery posted above.